# What is the necessity of aggregate functions in pivot table

Tags: sql, pivot

I have a table with data as

```
id id_1 id_2
1   C1   0
1   C2   0
1   C3   0
1   C4   1
2   C1   0
2   C2   0
2   C3   0
2   C4   0
3   C4   0
```

I am using pivot table to print the data

```
select *
from 
(
    select Id, id_1,id_2
    from table1
) x
pivot
(
    sum(id_2)
    for id_1 in ([C1], [C2], [C3], [C4])
) p
```

**question :** What is the necessity of using the aggregate function(`sum` in this case) when it is not required, as all the values are different. If i remove the aggregate function then it generates an error ( *this is the point which i am not undestanding*)

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e2012/1)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here all the values are different, but Oracle doesn't know this at parse time. Aggregation is required to ensure that there are no duplicates.

Yes, they possibly could have implemented this check at runtime and raise the exception if duplicates are found, but it just seems an arbitrary decision that it's not the case.